# The world of Listview

Tags: android, listview

I´m a beginner on developing for Android, and I´d like to understand how to create a more complex list view, as probably you saw in Google I/O 2010, so if you have any blog/book/website/sample or anything else that could help me understand this World, it'll help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf is a free excerpt from one of my books that gets into this.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I´m considering buy your book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope these links helps you:

[HowTo: ListView, Adapter, getView and different list items’ layouts in one ListView](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: thanks for the help, gonna move up the way how my listview look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Eclipse setup with the SDK I'd recommend downloading the api demos from the Android SDK Manager. There are quite a few ListView examples in there.

Comment: Well, API demos have quite few, not so complex samples and of course inexplicable.